# how to make code more readable with compiler optimizations in place?

Tags: c#, readability

Code is read more often then updated. Writing more readable code is better than writing powerful and geeky code when compilers can optimize for best execution.

For example see below code - this code can be compressed by combining the nested if statements, but will the compiler not optimize this code for best execution anyway while we get to maintain the readability of it?

```
// yeild sunRays when sky is blue.
// yeild sunRays when sky is not blue and sun is not present.
if (yieldWhenSkyIsBlue)
{
    // if sky is blue and sun is present -> yeild sunRaysObjB.
    if (sunObjA != null)
    {
        yield return sunRaysObjB;
    }
    else
    { 
       // do not yield ; 
    }    
}
else
{
    // if sky is not blue and sun is not present -> yeild sunRaysObjB.
    if (sunObjA == null)
    {
        yield return sunRaysObjB;
    }
}
```

As opposed to something like this :

```
// yeild sunRays when (sky is blue) or (sun is not present and sky is blue).
// (this interpretation is a bit misleading as compared to first one?)
if(( sunObjA == null && yieldWhenSkyIsBlue ==false) || (yieldWhenSkyIsBlue && sunObjA != null) )
{
    yield return sunRaysObjB;
}
```

Reading the first version depicts the use case better for future enhancements\updates ? The second version of the code is shorter but reading it does not make the use case very apparent or does it ? Are there other advantages of second case apart from concise code ?

**update #1** : yes it returns ObjB in both cases but based on the condition it may not yield at all. so the strategy decides when to yield and when not. ( one more reason why readability is imp)

**update #2** : updated to site a better example. copied the syntax from stripplingWarrior

**update #3** : updated for "What do you expect to happen when the sun is out and the sky is blue".

Comment: Do you have a typo in the code above? In both cases you are returning objB.

Comment: yes return ObjB in both cases but based on the condition it may not yield at all. so the strategy decides when to yield and when not.

Comment: I'm confused. So you get sun rays when the sky is not blue and the sun is not out?

Comment: +1 yeah.. the starting point is.   (1) yeild sunRays when sky is blue.
(2) yeild sunRays when sky is not blue and sun is not present.

Comment: @dotnetcoder: Your updated code is still not the equivalent of the first sample. If the sky is blue but the sun is not present, the first code will not yield rays, but your comment and the second code sample make it sound like you should yield rays whenever the sky is blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing it for fun or a specialized use case, I would argue human-readability is by far the more important quality of good code. The compiler is going to collapse much of your expressive code into more efficient forms, and what it misses you probably won't ever notice.

Given that, idiomatic code is easier to read even when it's less concise. Experienced readers of a language are going to recognize a common pattern more quickly than unfamiliar code that is, arguably 'more human' but breaks the familiar pattern.  Looping/incrementing constructs are a good example of code that should be unsurprising.  So, my approach is: Be expressive but not too clever.

Comment: Btw, a good book on the relationship of your code to what the compiler emits is: Write Great Code Volume 2: Thinking Low-level, Writing High-level.  http://www.amazon.com/Write-Great-Code-Low-Level-High-Level/dp/1593270658

Answer (score 7):

I think the second code example is much more readable, and has the advantage of being pretty optimal anyway.

Most programmers will find this logic flow to be obvious and natural: you will return ObjB if ObjA is null, or if it's not null and `howtoYieldFalg` is set.

*But* if I had to choose between making code like this more readable and making it optimal, I'd make it readable first. Only if I discovered that it's the source of a bottleneck would I bother optimizing it. In this particular case, I can pretty much guarantee that your use of `yield return` will introduce way more overhead than a suboptimal evaluation of your conditionals.

#### Update

Take another look at your code samples: they are not logically equivalent. What do you expect to happen when the sun is out *and* the sky is blue? The second code sample correctly allows sun rays to shine in that case, whereas the first example does not.

The fact that it was so easy to introduce a bug in the first case which so many people failed to catch for so long should be ample evidence to show that the second approach is better. All those nested `if/else` statements can be tricky to keep straight, even to an experienced programmer. Simple boolean logic is a lot easier to keep straight, especially once you use variable names that give it meaning.

#### Update 2

Based on the further explanation, and with a little creativity, I'm going to suggest an approach that uses both comments and variable names to increase clarity:

```
    /* Explanation: We live on a strange planet where the sun's
     * rays can shine if the sky is blue while the sun is out,
     * or if the sky is not blue and there is no sun. */
    bool sunIsPresent = sunObjA != null;
    if ((skyIsBlue && sunIsPresent) ||
        (!skyIsBlue && !sunIsPresent))
    {
        yield return sunRaysObjB;
    }
```

Comment: thanks i think your version is better suited as second option for this question.(copied your syntax).

Comment: if you notice now the second interpretation is a bit misleading.

Comment: "What do you expect to happen when the sun is out and the sky is blue" - expected is "do not yeild". and you rightly pointed out the second case ( i also missed) does not work the same way in this case.... or i can say in attempt to write shorter code i missed it.

Comment: i like it lot better! comments can be both direction (1) match requirements close to crypt code or (2) match crypt code backwards close to req. I have tried to take a simple example in this post. What i have seen usually is somebody later will update this code and not be able to decompose it in its bloated form ( case 1 ) which is 'good' to be able to make right decision. It just happened between us ... we missed one else case while dong the second version :) then corrected it.

Comment: @dotnetcoder: I find that comments should be used to give readers the "why" or the "big picture" of your code. On a line-by-line basis, you should be using variables and methods to make your code "self-commenting," so that any developer can glance at the code and know what the logic is going to do.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler optimizes right through any way you organize your program's control flow, so you really do not have to worry about it.

The weakness of compilers though, is they only optimize based on preserving code semantics, not preserving the meaning you intend. I compiled both your examples in LLVM, and here are the control flow graphs generated:

[image: first example]

and

[image: second example]

I was surprised to find the two CFG's are slightly different. You will note that first is an instruction smaller, but in the second graph, there exists a path to the exit node which only passes through one comparison, whereas in the first, two comparisons are always necessary.

In fact, further tracing of possible routes yields that the first example has possible routes of 6,8,8,6 instructions long, while the second has routes of 8,10,10 respectively. In BOTH cases the average run length is 7 instructions long, but we can see that the first case has better best-time run lengths. Without more information the compiler cannot tell which is better.

tldr: Compilers do magic stuff, don't worry about it, code how you think is best.

Comment: +1 for the detailed analysis, and for the conclusion. Don't be surprised that the code produces different paths, though: the two samples are not logically equivalent.

Comment: These examples are from the original code samples from the question. I ran the new statement from @StriplingWarrior through and it was optimized to one BasicBlock of 5 instructions. I modified the code slightly for simplicity by using integers instead of objects and whatnot, so LLVM used a simple XOR instruction to figure out whether to return '1' or '0'. Again, compilers are complex enough that *most* simple programs are optimized away.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. its a little confusing you see trying to fit the original ( more explicit ) condition into more syntactically "optimized" one. (i made the correction)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the popular opinion but I'd definitely not rely on the compiler to perform optimizations of this type. (It *may* do it, I don't know.) I don't see the second example as geeky - for me it describes more clearly that the two conditions are connected.

Typically I try to write as optimal code as possible without making it very cryptic and then let the compiler optimize that.

Comment: Agree,. A programmer having prbolems with form 2 should probably learn better programming and work moer - after some hundred more hours taht is natural. "geeky" is a funny term for programming in general - programmer  = geeks, so all programm code is geeky.

Answer (score 2):

Though I haven't tested this particular case, I'm willing to bet that there will be no significant difference between the generated code, if any at all.